# Comparing SQL statements from the file with the SQL statements stored in a database

Tags: sql, perl, oracle11g

I am parsing the statements from an SQL file (based on semicolon), executing them through `DBI`, and storing the statements which are executed successfully into Oracle database with "success" status.

If an error comes in the middle of executing the SQL file because of bad syntax, I will stop my Perl script and correct the mistake. When I restart the Perl script, I need to compare the statements from the file with the statements that are in the database marked as successful.

If a statement is already in the database I am not going to execute it again; I will just skip it. But if it is not there then I will start execution from that statement where it failed last time.

What is the best way to compare them? I tried to fetch the statements which are stored in the database, but I'm not able to get the entire statement.

How can I convert the big SQL statement into strings and store them in the database so that I can compare them using the `eq` operator?

Comment: Why don't you just parse the file, enqueue the statements, and then process the queue? No need to refer back to the file once it's been parsed.

Comment: Your approach is inherently flawed. Editing the file by hand makes *all* of the statements vulnerable to modification, including those that have already been executed. That means that your record may no longer match the contents of the file and your progress record is worthless. Also, *"I tried to fetch the statements which are stored in the database, but I'm not able to get the entire statement"* means  that you have a bug that needs to be fixed. Is it simply that your database field isn't big enough?

Comment: @MattJacob: What do you mean here by *"enqueue the statements"*? DBI has no queuing mechanism as such.

Comment: @Borodin He's already inserting the statements into the database with a status of `success` after they run. I'm suggesting separating the parsing and processing components and having the parser insert the statements into the table (the queue) with a `status` that indicates they need to be run. Every time it starts up, the processor looks for statements that need to be run and runs them.

Comment: @Borodin:I had given the long data type and I am able to see the entire statement was inserted into the data base.But  while fetching it back and storing it in perl variable,I was not getting the entire statement into the perl variable.Does new lines or tabs or spaces that are there in the sql statements will affect anything to not get back the entire statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this instead

- Read your file and split it on semicolons
- `prepare` each statement in the file and push the statement onto an array
- If any statement fails to parse, then report it and abandon processing
- Start a transaction
- `execute` each statement in turn from the array
- If any statement fails to execute then report it, roll back the transaction, and abandon processing
- Commit the transaction and terminate

Comment: Thanks Borodin .Your solution seems like the best one.I will try it.

Comment: :But this roll back will not going to roll back my DDL statements also RIGHT? It can only do for DML statements.Other than that your solution is perfect and best for my problem.